# Does PhotoStream copy videos too or just still photos?

Tags: photo-stream, ipad

If I use PhotoStream to sync photos from an iOS device and my Mac, will it transfer videos too? Are the higher resolution videos from the new iPad treated any differently than other devices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [iCloud Photo Stream FAQ](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4486?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US) says no - photos only.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, some research after posting the question tells me that the answer is **no** to the first question, making the second a rather trivial no also.

According to [Apple](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4486), PhotoStream is only for still-photos.

Comment: Annoying, but true. I can understand why it's undesirable to upload, store, and download videos from an internet service, but you'd think Apple could have been clever and done something like Dropbox LAN sync and sent the videos over wifi if it detected another interested party on the LAN

Comment: @KyleCronin -- see this answer http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/45368/9388